# I want to save time with unions of countable sets proof.

Tags: real-analysis

**This is my own work, for my enjoyment/benefit - self learning**

We've all seen how you can prove the rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$ are countable, you basically create a pair $(a,b)$ where $(a\in\mathbb{Z},b\in\mathbb{N_+})$ and show how to count it. This isn't what the question is about.

To save time (lots of inductions) I've opted to factor out my future inductions and do them now, I wish to show that:

---

Where $A$ is a countable set, with the set $B_n$ of vectors/arrays/tuples (language varies) of elements of $A$ is countable. That is for $b\in B_n$ we have $b=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ and $a_i\in A$ for $1\le i\le n$

I use $A \sim B$ to denote A being 1:1 with B (a bijection exists between the two) this is an equivalence relation.

my proof (which I want to know is correct) is as follows:

First consider $B_1$, this is trivially $\sim A$

suppose we have $B_{n-1}$ and it is countable.

We may write $B_n$ as $(b,a)$ which is $(b\in B_{n-1},a\in A)$

For a given $b\in B_{n-1}$ $(b,a)$ is countable ($\sim B_{n-1}$)

For a given $a\in A$ $(b,a)$ is countable ($\sim A$)

BUT only "for a given $b\in B_{n-1}$" is important, as in this case the set $(b,a)$ is countable. We then (somehow, I don't know how to write it) have the union of a countable number of countable sets.

We have the union of (b,a) where b is given over all the bs we can have (which are countable).

Comment: Are you allowed to use cardinal arithmetic?

Comment: @Dror I'm pretty sure I've got a proof, I'd really like the holes filled in. If there are any rules though it is that I must understand what is used!

Comment: 1. I *believe* I understand what you want to prove (It is not so clear in my opinion). 2. I hardly understand how to read your proof (It is very unclear), and I see not so accurate things where I *do* understand what I'm reading. So, if you want, try to edit your question to be as clear and detailed as you can make it.

Comment: @Dror for a given b the set (b,a) is countable (~A). So I have the union of a countable number of countable sets because my assumption was that $b\in B_{n-1}$ was countable. But I'll try.

Comment: I absolutely did *not* mean to say that what you think is wrong. It's just that *I* don't understand it :)

Comment: @Dror try now ? Also there's a "~" missing in the LaTeX that might explain why you were confused.

Comment: @AlecTeal: to denote the "~" equivalence relation symbol in LaTeX, try \sim, which produces $\sim$.

Comment: @AWertheim thanks, to flesh this comment out, the more I think about it the more certain I am that I can use the countable union of countable sets is countable theorem/collary/lemma I proved before this. I just don't know how to write it, wait! $$\cup_{b\in B_{n-1}}\cup_{a\in A}\{(b,a)\}$$ is closer, but not as neat, I am certainly close though!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just map them to $p_1$^$a_1$ * $p_2$^$a_2$ * ... * $p_n$^$a_n$
And $p_i$ prime